# spring integration leader election jdbc not working on disconnect

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use the leader election in spring-integration using JDBC. It works, as long as the database is connected. As soon as the database connection is dropped, the leader election stops working and the leader information on that node stays the same.

As far as I understood the code, there is an exception thrown when the connection is lost. The leader election then tries to remove the lock in the database (of course this is not possible) and another exception is thrown and the executor service stops running. (finally block in LockRegistryLeaderInitiator call() method)

Do I have to react on the database disconnection? Do I have to configure something?

Steps to reproduce:

- Start the first service
- check that it is the leader
- stop the database
- the instance is still the leader
- start the database again
- start a second instance
- both are now leader

dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

LeaderElectionConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class LeaderElectionConfiguration {

@Bean
public LockRegistry lockRegistry(LockRepository lockRepository) {
    return new JdbcLockRegistry(lockRepository);
}

@Bean
public DefaultLockRepository lockRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public LockRegistryLeaderInitiator leaderInitiator(LockRegistry lockRegistry) {
    LockRegistryLeaderInitiator lockRegistryLeaderInitiator = new LockRegistryLeaderInitiator(lockRegistry);
    lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.start();
    return lockRegistryLeaderInitiator;
}
```

}

jdbc config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    initialize: false
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/whatever
    username: admin
    password: adminpw
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 3):

I confirm this as a bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4447.

We indeed have a code in the `LockRegistryLeaderInitiator` like:

```
catch (Exception e) {
                    if (this.locked) {
                        this.lock.unlock();
                        this.locked = false;
                        // The lock was broken and we are no longer leader
                        handleRevoked();
                        if (isRunning()) {
                            // Give it a chance to elect some other leader.
                            Thread.sleep(LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.this.busyWaitMillis);
                        }
                    }
```

We really have to handle an exception from that `unlock()` and revoke leader independently of the result.

As a workaround I suggest to implement your own (just extend an existing `DefaultLockRepository` should be enough) and `try...catch()` exceptions in the `delete()` to let that `unlock` logic in the `LockRegistryLeaderInitiator` to proceed properly.